# Need example of select usage in AngularJS input form

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to use an array of objects

```
 (array = [{name: 'Moe', id:1}, {name: 'Larry', id:2}, {name: 'Curly', id:3}])
```

as a drop-down selection within an AngularJS input form, and I need an example badly.  Can anyone point me to a jsFiddle that can enlighten me?

Comment: If you want a jsFiddle, just go to the AnglarJS documentation on select http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select scroll down to the example given, and hit the Edit button and choose jsFiddle. Job done.

Answer (score 87):

I would recommend using ng-options where you can.

```
<select ng-model="choice" ng-options="x.id as x.name for x in array"></select>
```

Because check this out: You can use it to select *actual objects*:

```js
app.controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Foo' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Bar' }
    ];

    $scope.selectedItem = null;
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" 
            ng-options="item as item.name for item in items"></select>

    {{selectedItem | json}}
</div>
```

In the above example when you select something from the drop down, it's actually setting an entire object reference on selectedItem rather that just a value type.

NOTE: using ng-options sets your `value=""` attributes to the indices of the items in your collections *this is by design*.

It's really the best way to do it.

**EDIT: more context as requested. Also [here's a plunker showing it in use](http://plnkr.co/edit/6FAes1zgYYOSRCG4Jata)**

Comment: I hate to be a nag, but could you give me some more context, such as where the controller is referenced in the html?

Comment: is it possible with ng-options to add another option without id as a label? with the method in my answer below you can simply add another option outside of ng-repeat: `<option value="">Choose Something</option>`

Comment: Thank you for this code, I am just starting with Angular and I am struggling to understand what "item" is in your second ng-options example as it isn't mentioned in the script, what's it for and is it necessary?

Comment: so ng-options is like this... `[value] as [text] for [variable] in [collection]` ... so `item as item.name for item in items` is the same as `x as x.name for x in items`.

Comment: Ah I see, I have to say after I tried making an example it became much clearer, thank you :)

Comment: @BenLesh - I just wanted to say that your simple explanation and pseudo-code helped explain for me, in one line, what pages of verbose explanation have failed to do. They should add this single line to the documentation. Thank You!!

Comment: Setted is ok, but not displayed in select after view refreshed.

Comment: `x.id as x.name for x in array` does not work, also in your Plunker the values start from 0 and does not take the ids of your items.

Answer (score 21):

```
<select ng-model="choice">
    <option ng-repeat="obj in array" value="{{obj.id}}">{{obj.name}}</option>
</select>
```

or use 'ng-options' - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Comment: There's no reason to downvote this answer... it will work just fine, and in some cases it might be what people want.

Comment: I'm not the person who downvoted, but there are cases where this won't work properly.  In particular, if the `select` ng-model is not a string value.

Comment: I want to downvote but don't want to be rude. If you do this, then angular will bite you in the ass when you least expect it. 

I really wish this would work, but they had to go an obfruscate this directive to death.

Comment: Somehow, I get bad json in value if this child property)

Comment: This case was the best solution in my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

```
<dropdown-multiselect pre-selected="member.roles" model="selected_items" options="roles"></dropdown-multiselect>


<pre>selected roles = {{selected_items | json}}</pre>
```

Comment: If you add few lines of explanatory text you may receive a much higher feedback for this answer!